# rspec instance_variable_set where instance variable is an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

I'm trying to figure out how to write a test to check if a player has won in tic tac toe. I have an instance variable, @wins, initialized in this method:

```
class Game
attr_accessor :wins

def initialize(player1, player2)
   @player1 = player1
   @player2 = player2
   @rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

   @wins = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]

    @selected_numbers = []
    @counter = 0
end
```

I also have a method to check if a player has won:

```
def win?(token)
    @wins.each do |row|
        return true if row.all? { |input| input == "#{token}"}
    end

    false
end
```

I have tried to make an rspec test a bunch of different ways, but this is what I have right now (I know it is wrong):

```
describe "win?" do
    context "top row win" do
        it "returns true" do
            allow(game).to receive(:wins).and_return(["X", "X", "X"])

            expect(game.win?("X")).to eq(true)
        end
    end
end
```

My questions are: How can I improve this test to check to see if a player wins when the top row is all the same letter. And also, how can you set an instance variable in rspec when it is an array?

Edit: I tried expect game(......) instead of allow and it did not work either. I'm getting an error on expect(game.win?("X")).to eq(true) saying that expected is true but that it got false

Edit 2: I was able to get the test to work. My issue was not having two sets of array brackets in my instance_variable_set. Updated rspec test is below.

```
describe "win?" do
    context "top row win" do
        it "returns true" do
            game.instance_variable_set(:@wins, [["X", "X", "X"], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]])
            expect(game.win?("X")).to eq(true)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: rather than instance-variable setting... why don't you use `attr_accessor` and then you can use a stub in rspec instead eg: `expect(game).to receive(:wins).and_return(["X", "X", "X"])` or whatever...

Comment: Also: `"#{token}"` is token already a string? if so, you don't need to interpolate it into a string because it's already a string, just use `token`. If it's *not* a string, then the ruby-way is to call `to_s` on it instead eg `token.to_s`

Comment: thanks for your advice! I tried using attr_accessor on wins, but my test comes back now saying the result is false, when it is expected to be true

Comment: Can you show us that code? and the error? (edit your question rather than putting it here in the comments because code formatting in comments is dreadful) :)

Comment: okay just added the edit

Comment: `row.all? { |input| input == "#{token}"}` should this be `row.any?` instead of `row.all?` ? Also - try removing the string-interpolation around `token` and see what happens... you might be comparing an array against a string.